# Magento 2 - Grunt Watch in Vagrant Environment

Tags: magento2, css, grunt, vagrant

I'm running into this issue where when I ssh into my Vagrant VM and run `grunt watch` while editing css, it totally boggs down my system.  I hear the fan speed up and if left running, my VM grinds to a halt.  The workaround I've been using is to only run the task when I need to make a change, and then when it completes, I end the task.  My question is, is there any way I can just run `grunt watch` on my host machine?  I try to do this and it doesn't see any changes at all.  Part of me thinks it has something to do with the symlinks from `pub/static` to my working files.  Has anyone ever ran into this issue?

Comment: How is the folder mounted with your Magento code? Are you using the standard shared folder so the files are on your host? You could try to keep the Magento files *inside* of the VM and sync from outside .. but this also has drawbacks - never managed to build a perfect Vagrant setup on windows, so I made all our devs switch to Linux *g*

Answer (score -2):

**If you are use window system you need to run command prompt as Administator. 
Also, whenever you override files form the base theme you need to run following commnad**

```
1) grunt exec:themename
2) grunt watch
```

**After you have followed above step your changes will be reflect on forntend.
I hop it will help you.**